# how to serialize AMF body and send it with Ruby RocketAMF

Tags: ruby, amf

I am trying to serialized an AMF body and send it with RestClient.post.

From the Charles proxy, I can deserialized my request body and show it as follows:

```
# s is the raw binary from request body
pp RocketAMF::Envelope.new.populate_from_stream(s).messages
```

[image]

However, I cannot figure it out how to serialize such an object and send it (with RestClient.post) in the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to change the URL it's using, but the below is the correct way to do it.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'RocketAMF'
require 'rest-client'

data = [] # whatever data you want
env = RocketAMF::Envelope.new :amf_version => 3
env.messages << RocketAMF::Message.new('BatchController.authenticate_iphone', '/1', data)
res = RestClient.post "http://localhost:9292/amf", env.to_s, :content_type => 'application/x-amf'
puts RocketAMF::Envelope.new.populate_from_stream(res).inspect
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was trying to do env.messages = RocketAMF::Message.new('BatchController.authenticate_iphone', '/1', data)

Comment: I have an additional question about how to make the data array. In the added Charles deserialized AMF request screenshot, I have a property with "Object" Type and "Command" Value. I tried classmapping with `command = ClassCommand.new` and `RocketAMF::ClassMapper.define {|m| m.map :as => 'Command', :ruby => 'ClassCommand'}`, but it compalins with `rocketamf/class_mapping.rb:220:in block in props_for_serialization': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)`